# CurrentDb.Execute Error 3061 and DAO.Recordset Error

Tags: vba, ms-access

On a form, a user is able to select a value of either 1 or 2. This number is on an unbound control called CountVal.

When the user selects the submit button, an update query is ran. The following is the query.

```
UPDATE UserData_T SET UserQuantity = Forms!MainUser_F!CountVal.value;
```

The query, when run separately, runs as should. The issue comes when I call it in the submit button click event. I use the `CurrentDb.Execute` method. This method throws a

> 3061 error of "Too few parameters'.

I have found through much research that control based parameters do not work with the execute method. It works when I set the value as either 1 or 2 but not through the control. I need to have this dynamic.

I have also tried the `DAO.Database.OpenRecordset()` method, however I am struggling with looping through each record. Logically, I would gravitate to a for each but I'm not finding any references on using this loop with a DAO recordset. Also, wouldn't looping through the recordset be extremely slow? Could I also add an if statement to the query itself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In MS Access, stored queries can refer to open form or report controls as parameters. However, queries called via DAO methods like `CurrentDb.Execute`, do not see the GUI interface and hence cannot evaluate form or report controls.

So to continue using form controls as is, simply save your SQL statement as a stored query and call it with [`DoCmd.OpenQuery`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/access.docmd.openquery) (which do not need to be closed for action queries like  `UPDATE`, `INSERT`, `DELETE`). This is the coding counterpart to clicking the stored query via Navigation Pane.

```vb
DoCmd.OpenQuery "mySavedUpdateQuery"
```

Do note the above will raise prompts of data changes. To suppress such prompts, use [`DoCmd.SetWarnings`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/access.docmd.setwarnings):

```vb
DoCmd.SetWarnings False
DoCmd.OpenQuery "mySavedUpdateQuery"
DoCmd.SetWarnings True
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This solved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

You must concatenate the value to build the SQL:

```
Dim Sql As String

Sql = "UPDATE UserData_T SET UserQuantity = " & Forms!MainUser_F!CountVal.Value & ""
```

Comment: Adding an empty string at the end with `& ""` doesn't have any influence on the resulting string. Drop it!

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes: It is for completenes - shows that you haven't forgot a closing quote or octothorpe. You can leave it, if not according to your preferences.